# Why does the e-mail notification about a migrated question get sent a day later?

Tags: bug, migration, email, migrated-questions

I don't know that this is a "bug", but it certainly feels like one.

I just got an e-mail notification about [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72523194/css-to-force-a-container-to-properly-fit-around-embed-text-without-introduc) being moved to a more appropriate site.

Such notifications can be good, but:

- It was moved yesterday.
- I have already looked at the question on the second site yesterday.

So, why tell me about it:

- today rather than yesterday when it might have been useful to be told?
- or at all, since I'm obviously already aware of it?

[image]

"Visit question" button links to:

```
https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/ls/click?upn=FhKQFemTFIJzn5ywFPMHvn7nZiX7pHrbVxbFpLA1qbJBYA58lzxdVsU55RltVBa-2FbsbVx6KbofQcHrfFnO2UUXDpXucM2QMrOxIyI-2BFe-2BMr4mAJ0CMxBbFNcZijcSkl5-2BJlfiI17DlvwuGnGpE81hw-2BRVxZ9pDooBybhfiK1Ii1JsSYRoGNLg3fVZss-2BS3-2FnZZxK_oEmjqBbQKT6FCYkaR1V8hOFeg-2BP0Y7r9B57WvUv2w1Q4mHwS1KpN4kALK9kowAn0fEemv-2FAjxBu-2BCVqS2qBUG-2B0t5f-2FfZI8QbivPNMuNFemTaoZrnWLvowJaCDilYYcctiaCZC89UynO7UMeWg7T94ZVR677BSpWdjHMEO6G5-2FiT-2BmwaGP-2FMfKFKLujtigVEJQZTEOmbXix-2B70-2FqUgNcwM2S-2FNPHotby9vVFCkmijG3F-2BL4P6xOGrMpIlXN9b1QnN46yjirsVHGF6aYde1sRLR6t1ZfXqsT6YO1UoCLFHZbsrNQ1dn1sX-2BkCcs9lapSp6UK-2BRetfYHd8e4856lBpVMjxwHKKc1opByQtiRuTFix-2BGtotN5N5I14zLbrFWNovQyhXu3et2-2Fohuhn3EuSbmu54jKQ53mJhruhJzTWKAuFctCy14MCDgXYyJ-2F2s7ea884gEVNZeXR-2Byz24p24aqVr5copG2W50dOpqMhHvRa0-2FwtcJTEYyYz2jnFOtKQ5W3GExu-2FHh0ibTwUM2B6OLwt1FDO5UwLW23Bn5hCNeozbnPpvUTvut3tSYs1QpOrgbq
```

Mail header contains:

> Received: from MzU1Mzk4OA (unknown) by geopod-ismtpd-4-0 (SG) with HTTP id e0uRGqhSQfGl4Gi9lV_A7A Tue, 07 Jun 2022 20:33:51.042 +0000 (UTC)
> Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2022 20:33:51 +0000 (UTC)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the email without any identifying information? It might help us identify which email you're talking about. :)

Comment: @Catija. I've added the message, its "Visit question" link, and part of its mail header.

Comment: @Catija, I just noticed that the mail suggests that I "join Stack Overflow".  Perhaps the bug is that it doesn't realize that I am already a member?

Comment: @RayButterworth It's static text. It always displays the same line to every person.

Comment: The email probably isn't aware of whether you saw the notification or not but I'm curious why it was delayed. I see that you have emails set to daily but I don't think this one should be impacted by that setting. I'd have to get a developer to check and explain the proper timing, probably.